# What are Sam Beckett's educational qualifications?

Tags: quantum-leap

What six (or is it seven?) doctorates does Sam Beckett  hold?  Are they ever listed in full in the show or anywhere else?

Comment: He had PHDs in stepping into quantum leap accelerators and in vanishing.

Comment: Al mentions that he has seven "advanced degrees" in a later episode. An advanced degree isn't the same as a doctorate and could basically be his Masters Degree in any of the subjects in which he has a doctorate.

Answer (score 3):

We learn that he has a six doctorates in the pilot episode. Five are directly stated within the show and one appears in a licenced tie-in novel.

His doctorates are in **Medicine, Quantum Physics, Ancient Languages, Music, Archaeology, Electrical Engineering**. He also holds a **Bachelor's degree and a Master's degree in Physics from MIT.**

---

- **Medicine and Quantum Physics.** ([Genesis, Part I](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis:_Part_I_(episode)))

> **Sam:** *No, no. See, I'm a medical doctor. I found that much out.*
>
> **Al:** *You hold six doctorates, Sam. **Medicine** is just one of them. Your special gift was **quantum physics***.

- **Ancient languages** ([Star-Crossed](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Star-Crossed_(episode)))

> **Al:** *You know, uh, those six doctorates that you hold, not one of them is in psychiatry. **Medicine**, yes. Uh, **quantum physics**, yes. **Ancient languages**, yes.*

- **Music** ([A Song for the Soul](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/A_Song_For_The_Soul_(episode)))

> **Sam:** *I read **music**, right?*
>
> **Al:** *You have a doctorate in it.*

- **Archaeology/Egyptology** ([The Curse of Phah-Hotep](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/The_Curse_of_Ptah-Hotep_(episode)))

> **Sam:** *This is bigger than King Tut. We can't walk away from this now. **I did a thesis on this guy.** This is a chance of a lifetime.*

- **Electrical Engineering** (This one comes from the tie-in novel [Prelude: Quantum Leap #4](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Prelude))

> ... what a computer needed was not just fuzzy logic but the power of human inspiration. He had gone after and gotten a **doctorate in medicine** so that he could better understand the human brain, in **physics** and **electrical engineering** and other things so that he could design the tissue cells for the new computer.

---

- **Another tie-in novel ([Knights of the Morningstar](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Morningstar)) advises us that he has Bachelor's and Master's degrees in physics.** This would account for Al stating that he has "**seven** degrees" (e.g. not six) in [Shock Theatre](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Shock_Theater_(episode)).

> College: Massachusetts Institute of Technology, B.S. and M.S. and Ph.D. in Physics...